# Android Studio Version 3.0 Canary Channel Not Rendering Support Libraries

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I'm developing an app using versio 3.0 of Android Studio (the app is in kotlin) and the rendering simply stopped working. I remember the last significant update I did was to update the kotlin plugin to the latest version, but no matter what I do it will not render the support library components (Coordinator Layout, Nested Scroll Views, Recycler Views...)
Here's a list of things I've already tried:

- Update to the latest version of the sdk tools, the kotlin plugin and the build/compile tools
- Invalidate Cache
- Changed API version in Editor
- Changed theme in editor

Here's a peak of my grandle dependencies

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
  {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk21:0.9.1'
  compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:0.10.1'
  compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:0.10.1'
  compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
  compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
  compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
  compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.0'
  compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
  compile 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.0.4'
  compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
}
```

And for the kotlin version in my project level gradle file:

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
```

Normally, under the preview editor I keep receiving this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:56)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:120)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:215)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.defineClassAndPackage(RenderClassLoader.java:177)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:92)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:172)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:56)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:120)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:215)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:500)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:254)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:334)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:382)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:591)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:739)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Which is really strange because all necessary support libraries have been added.

Comment: have you download the `android:support-v4` for the new android version 3.0 by android sdk manager?

Comment: I did yes. For now I had to switch back to AS 2.3.3 and everything is working fine.